# Next.js does not load base64 encoded image from API

Tags: reactjs, rest, image-processing, next.js, lazy-loading

I am using Next.js which loads HTML from an external API.
This API returns HTML with images as follows: The data-src is the actual external URL. The src attribute is base64 encoded.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,Base64_String.." data-src="https://example.com" />
```

Next.js renders the HTML code fine except the images. How can i show the images with Next.js? Do i need specific settings or an package? My preference is loading using lazy loading by the way.

Comment: Next.js provides a built-in component for handling images [link to docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image). And if images are still not showing, you need to configure your next. config file

Comment: I don't see any flaw in your piece of code. If the base64 is valid and html is rendered without being escaped, it should work just fine. Next.js can also render <img /> tag like normal html if it's done the right way.

Could you share more on what's the outcome that the image with base 64 is not working?

Comment: @SulemanElahi the Next provider for images, is optional right? I have added the remotepattern URL, because i am trying to load images from another hostname. It doesn't change the output.

Comment: @KayasitR the output is blank/empty line with this code. If i change the src string to the data-src strings value the image is shown. Maybe the base64 code is not a valid URL, is it possible to check that?